# select specific link by href with webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, rspec2, webrat

I'm writing an integration test for rspec and I want to test that clicking on a link goes to the correct model page. More specifically, I want to test this on a list of links that have the same name but different underlying URLs.

From what I've learned so far, you cannot use a css attribute selector with click_link as it only looks for specific text or dom ID. Instead I'm trying to use the webrat `within` method, but once I select the link how do I click it? I figured `link.click` within the link's scope would work, but it fails saying the method `click` is undefined:

```
Failure/Error: link.click
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `click' for #<Webrat::Scope:0x0000010505ae00>
```

Here's my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "BrandLinks" do
  before(:each) do
    @base_title = "My App - "

    @brand = Factory(:brand)
    second = Factory(:brand) # <= Same name, different slug
    third = Factory(:brand, :name => "Awesome USA Brand!!")
    @brands = [@brand, second, third]
  end

  it "should show me the brand page when I click on a brand link" do
    get '/brands'
    within "a[href=#{brand_path(@brand)}]" do |link|
      link.click
    end
    response.should be_success
    response.should have_selector(
      "title", 
      :content => "#{@base_title}Brand - #{@brand.name}"
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: The seemingly obvious answer here is to just add some more selectors to the page so I can select a parent node of the link. If I were to do that at this point I would only be adding selectors to the page for the sake of passing this one test. I'd like to avoid doing that.

Comment: A colleague had the following to say about my previous comment: `[When] code is easy to test, it's often a sign that the architecture is coherent and decoupled.  I have definitely changed/refactored code purely for testability. I would certainly be more wary of doing this if it actually made the code more complex, but adding an id to an html element, for example, doesn't really increase your technical debt. If it makes the code more testable, I'd say go for it. If the element is important enough for you to test that it's there, it's probably fine for you to give it an id or class.` Point taken

Comment: That said, I'd still like to know if what I was trying is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [click_link_within](http://rubydoc.info/github/brynary/webrat/master/Webrat/Session#click_link_within-instance_method)? According to the docs

> Works like click_link, but only looks for the link text within a given selector

Comment: It sounds like I will be facing the same problem. The only selector to find on is the href of the link itself. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That fails with `Failure/Error: click_link_within "a[href='#{brand_path(@brand)}']", @brand.name
Webrat::NotFoundError:Could not find link with text or title or id "Super Brand A"`, so it must be looking for a link within that link.

Comment: It's supposed to work with xpath but there's apparently a bug in webrat. I don't know if it's been fixed but here's some info and a workaround https://webrat.lighthouseapp.com/projects/10503-webrat/tickets/153-within-should-support-xpath

Comment: Also, another option that people often recommend is to use capybara instead of webrat.

Comment: @Dty - That might work. I don't suppose you could tell me how to apply that forked patch to my webrat gem? Or do I need to clone it, build it and `gem install` using the local copy?

Comment: I've never done it myself but I would clone, patch, gem install local copy. But did you see this link yet? http://objectliteral.blogspot.com/2009/09/clicking-on-links-in-webrat-using-xpath.html You should try `click_link(link)`

Comment: I did see that post, but it was unclear what link and link_id referred to. He doesn't specify a local variable in the within block, so I'm guessing it's not "link" and that link is just a placeholder for the text or ID one would normally use. I'm pretty sure the click functions don't accept an object as reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message is that the `.click` method is undefined. Try `.click_link` instead.

You'll also need the text of the link.  That is, `within` defines a scope, and `click_link` tells it which link to click inside that scope.

```
within "a[href=#{brand_path(@brand)}]" do |scope| # within a specific <a> tag
  scope.click_link @brand # click on @brand text
end
```

[`click_link_within`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/webrat/0.7.1/Webrat/Session%3aclick_link_within) is a shortcut for within plus click_link, so this should be identical to the above:

```
click_link_within "a[href=#{brand_path(@brand)}]", @brand
```

I'm still trying to understand how the `within` selectors work myself (which is how I found this question!).  Here's what I've got so far:

The Webrat Session object's [`within` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/webrat/0.7.1/Webrat/Session%3awithin) takes a `selector` argument, which it uses to push a new scope onto a stack by passing the selector to [Scope.from_scope](http://rubydoc.info/gems/webrat/0.7.1/Webrat/Scope.from_scope), which creates a new session with `@selector = selector`. So far I can't find the definition of `selector`.  This [2009 blog post](http://devblog.imedo.de/2009/11/12/matching-elements-on-complex-web-pages-with-webrat/) says a selector can be a CSS type, class, or ID, but it doesn't cite a source for that.